# Showing URL in bibliography using Overleaf and Mendeley

Tags: bibliographies

I'm using [Overleaf](http://www.overleaf.com) to write in Latex, I'm also integrated [Mendeley](http://www.mendeley.com) to generate bibliograpahy. Here is example web page entry generated by Mendeley.

```
@misc{DockerReference,
    title = {{Docker Reference}},
    booktitle = {2016},
    url = {https://docs.docker.com}
}
```

I'm joggling different bibliography stylies because I'm trying to display URL's in bibliography.

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{Mendeley}
```

I've no idea how to do that. It's worth to mention that I can't edit bibliography file by my self in overleaf, so I can't change *.bib file.

Comment: `unsrt` doesn't support URL fields; try `\bibliographystyl{unsrtnat}` instead (you'll also need `\usepackage{natbib} and `\usepackage{url}` or `hyperref`)

Comment: It's partialy solved my problem, but now numbers are missing

Comment: `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Style `unsrt` doesn't support URL fields; try `\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}` instead.

You'll also need `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}`, and `\usepackage{url}` or `\usepackage{hyperref}` for proper handling of special characters (underscores etc) in the URLs.